# substitute string with an empty string in a xml file

Tags: xml, bash

I received an xml file which has been extracted by someone else from a DB. the problem is that it contains some string that are creating problems to read the xml in a correct way. Here it is a small part of it:

```
<gmd:fileIdentifier xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx">\r\n    <gco:CharacterString>0211fa18-e0a4-4d2ed26-7580726e593c</gco:CharacterString>\r\n  </gmd:fileIdentifier>\r\n  <gmd:language>\r\n    <gco:CharacterString>eng</gco:CharacterString>\r\n  </gmd:language>\r\n  <gmd:hierarchyLevel>\r\n    <gmd:MD_ScopeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode" codeListValue="dataset" />\r\n  </gmd:hierarchyLevel>\r\n  <gmd:contact>\r\n    <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>\r\n      <gmd:organisationName>\r\n        <gco:CharacterString>Research</gco:CharacterString>\r\n      </gmd:organisationName>\r\n      <gmd:contactInfo>\r\n        <gmd:CI_Contact>\r\n          <gmd:address>\r\n            <gmd:CI_Address>\r\n              <gmd:electronicMailAddress>\r\n                <gco:CharacterString>pippo@gmail.com</gco:CharacterString>\r\n              </gmd:electronicMailAddress>\r\n            </gmd:CI_Address>\r\n          </gmd:address>\r\n        </gmd:CI_Contact>\r\n      </gmd:contactInfo>\r\n
```

As you can see at the end of each tag there is the string "\r\n" which is the problem.
I tried using the following bash command:

```
string='\r\n'
sed -i 's/$string/''/g' test.xml
```

but it is not working, no empty string is substituting the $string variable.

could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `string` variable contains `\r\n` as special characters sequence. But you need you to replace it literally as it go within your input file.

Use the following **sed** approach:

```
sed 's#\\r\\n##g' test.xml
```

The output (for your current input fragment):

```
<gmd:fileIdentifier xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx">    <gco:CharacterString>0211fa18-e0a4-4d2ed26-7580726e593c</gco:CharacterString>  </gmd:fileIdentifier>  <gmd:language>    <gco:CharacterString>eng</gco:CharacterString>  </gmd:language>  <gmd:hierarchyLevel>    <gmd:MD_ScopeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode" codeListValue="dataset" />  </gmd:hierarchyLevel>  <gmd:contact>    <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>      <gmd:organisationName>        <gco:CharacterString>Research</gco:CharacterString>      </gmd:organisationName>      <gmd:contactInfo>        <gmd:CI_Contact>          <gmd:address>            <gmd:CI_Address>              <gmd:electronicMailAddress>                <gco:CharacterString>pippo@gmail.com</gco:CharacterString>              </gmd:electronicMailAddress>            </gmd:CI_Address>          </gmd:address>        </gmd:CI_Contact>      </gmd:contactInfo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following awk may help you in same.

```
awk '{gsub(/\\r\\n/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply using awk's gsub utility which will globally substitute \r\n with NULL, point to be noted here \r and \n is written to eliminate \ special meaning here and it should take it literal character and not it's special meaning. 1 will print the lines.

Answer (score 1):

`\r\n` are Windows line endings.

I don't know which XML parser you're using or which programming language but try to convert the file first to Unix format by invoking `dos2unix your-file.xml` and then feed it to your parser. You can also convert it with common text editors.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using linux and I tried using dos2unix cmd but it was not enough. Since it might be that I have to make this substitution to a great number of files, unfortunately I have to find an automatic way for doing it. thanks for your hint!!

Comment: Without seeing your file it's a little difficult to say which bytes are causing problems but I've fallen across it several times and solved it easily with `dos2unix`. For doing it on many files there's always the good old pipe and/or for loop.

Answer (score 1):

`\` must be escaped because `\r` sequence in sed is changed to carriage return character

```
string='\\r\\n'
```

also variable expansions are done between double quotes but not between signle quotes

```
sed -i "s/$string//g" test.xml
```

Note in general any string can't be used because of injections if contains `/`, this is a general problem with code generation.

Comment: yes you are right but even using the escape character it was not working if I used my cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
sed 's/\\r\\n//g' test       #test has the line


[user@ip check]$ sed 's/\\r\\n//g' test
<gmd:fileIdentifier xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx">  <gco:CharacterString>0211fa18-e0a4-4d2ed26-7580726e593c</gco:CharacterString> </gmd:fileIdentifier>  <gmd:language>    <gco:CharacterString>eng</gco:CharacterString>  </gmd:language>  <gmd:hierarchyLevel>    <gmd:MD_ScopeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode" codeListValue="dataset" />  </gmd:hierarchyLevel>  <gmd:contact>    <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>      <gmd:organisationName>        <gco:CharacterString>Research</gco:CharacterString>      </gmd:organisationName>      <gmd:contactInfo>        <gmd:CI_Contact>          <gmd:address>            <gmd:CI_Address>              <gmd:electronicMailAddress>                <gco:CharacterString>pippo@gmail.com</gco:CharacterString>              </gmd:electronicMailAddress>            </gmd:CI_Address>          </gmd:address>        </gmd:CI_Contact>      </gmd:contactInfo>
```